# Can someone explain why my first ggplot2 box plot was just one big box and how the solution worked?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So my first ggplot2 box plot was just one big stretched out box plot, the second one was correct but I don't understand what changed and why the second one worked. I'm new to R and ggplot2, let me know if you can, thanks.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
#    This is the original ggplot that didn't work:
#----------------------------------------------------------
zSepalFrame <- data.frame(zSepalLength, zSepalWdth)
zPetalFrame <- data.frame(zPetalLength, zPetalWdth)

p1 <- ggplot(data = zSepalFrame, mapping = aes(x=zSepalWdth, y=zSepalLength, group = 4)) +  #fill = zSepalLength
  geom_boxplot(notch=TRUE) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.2) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Iris Data Box Plot") +
  labs(subtitle ="Z Values of Sepals From Iris.R")

p1
```

```
#----------------------------------------------------------
#    This is the new ggplot box plot line that worked:
#----------------------------------------------------------

bp = ggplot(zSepalFrame, aes(x=factor(zSepalWdth), y=zSepalLength, color = zSepalWdth)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.position = "none")
bp
```

[This is what the ggplot box plot looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yVHK.png)

Comment: Why did you include `group = 4` in the `aes()` in the first one? That tells ggplot that all the values come from the same group (group #4 -- but you could have but any number there, it would have been the same.).

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Best we can do is guess until then, but you had a boxplot over a continuous variable (x-axis) when you generally want it to be grouped by a discrete variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your precise dataset, OP, but it seems to stem from assigning a continuous variable to your x axis, when boxplots require a discrete variable.

A **continuous** variable is something like a numeric column in a dataframe.  So something like this:

```
x <- c(4,4,4,8,8,8,8)
```

Even though the variable `x` only contains 4's and 8's, `R` assigns this as a numeric type of variable, which is continuous.  It means that if you plot this on the x axis, `ggplot` will have no issue with something falling anywhere in-between 4 or 8, and will be positioned accordingly.

The other type of variable is called **discrete**, which would be something like this:

```
y <- c("Green", "Green", "Flags", "Flags", "Cars")
```

The variable `y` contains only characters.  It *must* be discrete, since there is no such thing as something between `"Green"` and `"Cars"`.  If plotted on an x axis, `ggplot` will group things as either being `"Green"`, `"Flags"`, or `"Cars"`.

The cool thing is that you can change a **continuous** variable into a **discrete** one.  One way to do that is to factorize or force `R` to consider a variable as a factor.  If you typed `factor(x)`, you get this:

```
[1] 4 4 4 8 8 8 8
Levels: 4 8
```

The values in `x` are the same, but now there is no such thing as a number between 4 and 8 when `x` is a factor - it would just add another level.

That is in short why your box plot changes.  Let's demonstrate with the `iris` dataset.  First, an example like yours.  Notice that I'm assigning `x=Sepal.Length`.  In the `iris` dataset, `Sepal.Length` is numeric, so **continuous**.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

This is similar to yours.  The reason is that the boxplot is drawn by grouping according to x and then calculating statistics on those groups.  If a variable is continuous, there are no "groups", even if data is replicated (like as in `x` above).  One way to make groups is to force the data to be discrete, as in `factor(Sepal.Length)`.  Here's what it looks like when you do that:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=factor(Sepal.Length), y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

The other way to have this same effect would be to use the `group=` aesthetic, which does what you might think: it groups according to that column in the dataset.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length), y=Sepal.Width, group=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation.